# Make parent div same width as child, and ignore parent

Tags: html, css

I have a parent, child, and grandchildren `divs`. The grandchildren need to be displayed in rows, not columns. I'm trying to get the child to have the same width as the grandchildren, (the child's children,) but at the same time, I want the parent to retain its height of the grandchildren.

I tried making the child to `position: absolute`, but the problem with that is, the parent doesn't retain the child, and grandchildren's height.

How can I make the parent have the same height as its descendants, while having a different width. And have the child have the same width as the grandchildren?

#### JSFiddle

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#wrapper {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 220px;
}
#innerWrapper {
  display: flex;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
.item {
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 5px;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
#other {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="innerWrapper">
    <div class="item">Item - 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item - 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item - 3</div>
    <div class="item">Item - 4</div>
    <div class="item">Item - 5</div>
    <div class="item">Item - 6</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="other">I'm another element</div>
```

Comment: See my post and let me know if I'm close to your objective.

Answer (score 1):

#### UPDATE

OP wanted:

1. grandma at 220px so I gave her `max-width:220px`
2. mom fitting kids like shrink-wrap extending past grandma. I gave her `position:relative` to escape grandma's flow, `min-width: 635px` which is a total of the kids width with margins included, `min-height:110px` which is the height of a kid plus margins.
3. kids `display: inline-block`, `position: absolute`. I then gave them a `left` of an interval of accumulative values of 105px using this `nth` selector:

   ```
   div div div:nth-of-type(X) {
       left:105px++
   }
   ```

   See Snippet for a clearer picture.

Mom has a semi-transparent background so you can see grandma in black.

`#other` was given `position:relative` and `top:110px` to move it out of the way.

<del>I think I understand what you are after. In this Snippet, I gave:</del>

<del>1. grandma `display:table` and `table-layout:fixed`</del>
 <del>2. mom `display:table-row`</del>
 <del>3. kids `display:table-cell`</del>

<del>I added a dashed border, `border-spacing`, and a semi-transparent background to show the presence of grandma and mom. Those additions are optional. I removed the flexbox properties as well.</del>

#### SNIPPET (Revised)

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#wrapper {
  background-color: black;
  max-width: 220px;
  float: left;
}
#innerWrapper {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 200, .5);
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  min-width: 635px;
  min-height: 110px;
}
.item {
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}
div div div:nth-of-type(2) {
  left: 105px;
}
div div div:nth-of-type(3) {
  left: 210px;
}
div div div:nth-of-type(4) {
  left: 315px;
}
div div div:nth-of-type(5) {
  left: 420px;
}
div div div:nth-of-type(6) {
  left: 525px;
}
#other {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  top: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="innerWrapper">
    <div class="item">Item - 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item - 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item - 3</div>
    <div class="item">Item - 4</div>
    <div class="item">Item - 5</div>
    <div class="item">Item - 6</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="other">I'm another element</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! but I need grandma (`#wrapper`) to have a width of `220px`

Comment: No prob, just a min., did you want the kids to extend past grandma?

Comment: Yes, I want mom and moms kids to extend past grandma

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `flux-box` from your style and remove the `width` in your child. I have added the [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/edrxsy6u/4/)

Comment: You forgot the link for the demo... oops

Comment: Oh ... Sorry i make it codded, so the link didnt work :)

Comment: um... it's not rows, it's columns.

Comment: Thanks, but I want `#wrapper` to stay in the flow. Meaning, I want everything that's supposed to be under, to be right under it.